# How to package and release a Ruby application?

Tags: ruby, homebrew, packaging

I,ve got a Ruby app (so no Rails!) and want to release it to 'the public'. On my mac, I've set up the `$PATH` to include the `bin` directory of my app, so I can just type `executable_name` as a command.

However, when somebody installs the app, they would have to add the `bin` directory to their `$PATH` like I did. This is not as easy as I would like. Is it possible to let users install with Homebrew or something similar? Or maybe I'm missing something I did't know about? How do you guys generally go about this?

For the sake of completeness -> the file structure:

```
|- my_application

   |- bin
      |- executable

   |- lib
      |- my_class.rb
      |- my_class.rb
      |- my_class.rb

   |- tests
      |- my_tests.rb
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Ruby` any lib/application called `gem` and should be installed via `rubygems`. Read [`how make your own gem`](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/). This all what you need.

[`It is contain section about adding executable`](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/#adding-an-executable)

Comment: Thanks! Very complete guides! I was under the impression gems where only for use with Rails, but I guess I was wrong! :)